# Java socket send data from client to server

Tags: java, sockets

Why gets `NullPointerException`?  When I send data from server to client it  all ok.

```
Error java.lang.NullPointerException
at NetworkClient.Klient.wyslijDane(Klient.java:35)
```

EDIT Code 
I Added complete server class and client class
In other  class i create a new  Object Client and Server

klient=new Klient();
and then  call method WyslijDane.  Server it's  ok, and  client throw exception.

Client  Class

```
public class Klient {

  public static final int PORT=50007;
  public static Socket sock;
  public static int msg=10;



public Klient() throws UnknownHostException, IOException
{
    Socket sock=new Socket("localhost", PORT);
}



 public static void wyslijDane(int GraczK) throws IOException
{

      DataInputStream in=new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
       DataOutputStream out=new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());

      //    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));



          out.writeInt(GraczK);
         //out.writeBoolean(flaga);
          out.flush();
         System.out.println("Wyslano dane "+ GraczK );
}
}
```

Server Class

```
 public class Server
  {
   public static final int PORT=50007;
   public static MainWarSever main=new MainWarSever();
   static Socket sock;   
             public Server() throws IOException
 {
     //tworzenie gniazda serwerowego                                        
     ServerSocket serv = null;                                                     
     if (serv==null)
     serv=new ServerSocket(PORT);
     else 
     {
         System.out.println("SErver już zajety brrrr");
         serv.close();
     }




                                                                    sock=serv.accept();                                                    
    System.out.println("Jest polaczenie: "+sock);   

 }


 public static void wyslijDane(int GraczK) throws IOException
 {
      DataInputStream in=new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
      DataOutputStream out=new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());

        boolean flaga=true;
        int msg;
        int i=0;
        int msgOut;
         msgOut=GraczK;
         out.writeInt(msgOut);
         out.writeBoolean(flaga);
         out.flush();
         System.out.println("Wyslano dane "+ GraczK + "Flage" + flaga);
}
```

Comment: Wich one is line 35?

Comment: its this line  35     
DataOutputStream out=new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());

Set Sock Client
 public static final int PORT=50007;
 public static Socket sock;
 public static int msg=10;

 
 
 public Klient() throws UnknownHostException, IOException
 {
  Socket sock=new Socket("localhost", PORT);
 }

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the part of code where you create the socket (on the client side)?

Comment: OK  I was edit my  question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Your are getting the `NullPointerException` because when you say `sock.getOutputStream()` or `sock.getInputStream()` you're using the `sock`
 variable declared outside the constructor wich is not initialized.

So instead of creating a new `sock` variable in the constructor use the one you already have:

```
//Change this line
Socket sock=new Socket("localhost", PORT);

//To this
Socket sock=new Socket("localhost", PORT);
```

2) Your sock variable shouldn't be declared as `static` and the `wyslijDane` should be called after the constructor is executed (the socket created) so it shouldn't be static.

3) Make sure you call the `wyslijDane` method after you create the `Socket`.

4) First create and flush the `DataOutputStream` and then create the `DataInputStream`. They should be in the same order both in the client and in the server code:

```
DataOutputStream out=new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
out.flush();
DataInputStream in=new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
```

Since you said the exception is thrown when you create the `DataOutputStream` the problem should be solved.

---

Suggestion:

As a good practice, don't create the `DataOutputStream` and the `DataInputStream` everytime you call the `wyslijDane` method.
Instead create the `DataOutputStream` and the `DataInputStream` just after you create the socket.

Answer (score 1):

What is `sock` set to? If `sock` is not the reason for the NullPointerException, code with line numbers would be helpful.

EDIT: After you've added your complete source code ... when calling static `wyslijDane(int GraczK)` your `Klient()` constructor setting sock must not have been called. Making your variables and methods not-static would clarify this.

EDIT: BTW in your client class you define *two* sock variables, one static and one in the constructor, the latter is destroyed after leaving the constructor.